# A* Search Algorithm gets stuck

Tags: search, xna, a-star

I am trying to implement an A* Search algorithm. For now I am just trying to find a good path through an environment littered with walls. The walls are randomly generated, and in some cases my path gets "stuck". If the search encounters a wall in front of it, and to all of its sides (except the one that led it into this mess), it stops.
Is there something I can do to prevent this? I am using a "as the crow flies" point system for my H value, which ignores the walls and just estimates how far it will take to get to the destination. This sometimes leads it into this trap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underestimating the distance is 'proper' for A*.

But it sounds like you have a depth/breadth problem.

When evaluating options from a given position, you should add them to a list of options to check and sort them by score. There should be no reason why you would check the options available from a given position immediately after you've evaluated that position - i.e. all options from each position should go into the same list. This way, when you hit a dead end, it simply does not generate further options and you proceed by taking the next highest scored option off the list and evaluating that.

Comment: I've got it fixed, it had to do with getting another "Node" from my list of Open Options. The problem was it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking of the state space like a Directed Acyclic Graph, if A* encounters a leaf node that isn't a terminal node, it shouldn't be a problem, since that node will simply have been already moved to the closed list.

If your implementation of A* immediately stops after encountering a non-terminal (goal) leaf node, and there are other nodes still on the open list, then your implementation of A* is incorrect.

Comment: This is the problem. I have something wrong with how I implementing it. I'm looking into it more, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's led into a dead-end, it shouldn't be a problem. Your A* algorithm should simply find the next *non-blocked* node with the lowest heuristic and start over.